# How can I create a modern responsive sharepoint website that is for outside users, without looking like sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I'm creating a website for a undergrad research project and have to use sharepoint. I have already come up with designers for the website and want to write custom hmtl/ css/ js code to implement all the design and necessary features. I will also need to use a server-side language to interact with a database as I will need student and teacher relational profiles. I have edited an .aspx page on sharepoint designer but when I test it - it doesn't show the nav bar or anything. What is the best way to go about this? I know how to do this with regular code but don't know how to do it with sharepoint. Maybe sharepoint designer? Looking for the best way to create a good looking website. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What SharePoint version are you using? What do you mean by "outside users", don't they have an account to access your SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

First, let me tell you that you cannot create a public facing site with SharePoint to access. this can be achieved with [PowerApps Portal](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/portals/). If you are looking for customization for SharePoint sites with modern experience you may refer to [Look book](https://lookbook.microsoft.com/)

Comment: You certainly can use SharePoint to host a publicly facing website.  You just can’t use SharePoint Online for the task.

Comment: my comment was phrased that way because question carries SharePoint-Online tag.

Comment: Sorry.  I swear I looked.  Must've missed it.